# Loading different urls in webview depending on segue from alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

In my app, there are different buttons that trigger different alert views. Each one has an option to click "More Information" which directs to the same UIWebView. I want to load a different url in the webview depending on which alert directed it to the webview. 
I tried creating different segue identifiers and have attached that code. But the webview is blank/doesn't load the url. Is there a way to make this work using different segue identifiers? Or is there a better way to do this where I can use the same segue for all of the alerts but still load different urls in the webview? How do I tell the webview which one to load?

HomeViewController.m

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

if (buttonIndex == 1){
    if (alertView.tag==1) {

        [self moreInfo];
    }
}


}

-(void) moreInfo{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"morebainfo" sender:nil];

}
-(void)ftmoreinfo{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moreftinfo" sender:nil];

}


- (IBAction)bainfo:(id)sender {

UIAlertView *baAlert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bacillus anthracis"
                                                         message:@"This is the message."
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:@"More Information", nil];

baAlert.tag=1;
[baAlert show];
}
- (IBAction)ftinfo:(id)sender {

UIAlertView *ftAlert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Francisella tularensis"
                                                 message:@"This is the message."
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"More Information", nil];




[ftAlert show];
}
```

WebViewController.m

```
@interface MoreInfoViewController ()

@end

@implementation MoreInfoViewController
@synthesize MoreInfoWeb;
@synthesize loadUrl;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"morebainfo"]){
    MoreInfoViewController *webview = [segue destinationViewController];
    webview.loadUrl = @"http://example.com/";
}



}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

NSURL *urlToLoad = [NSURL URLWithString:self.loadUrl];
[self.MoreInfoWeb loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToLoad]];


}
```

Comment: are you getting the appropriate url in your MoreInfoWeb's loadUrl,

Comment: Please post your `loadUrl` property header declaration.

Comment: @Geet I am not sure if I know what you mean..

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *loadUrl;

Comment: Ok that looks fine. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: okay! any idea why the webview is still showing up blank?

Comment: I meant try to put a log loadUrl  of in your MoreInfoWeb's viewDidload method method and see whether the URL is being passed

Comment: okay did that. and the URL does not seemed to be passed. but i'm not sure why not

Comment: ended up figuring it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up fixing it:

I moved the prepare for segue method to the initial view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);


if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"morebainfo"]){
    MoreInfoViewController *webview = [segue destinationViewController];
    webview.loadUrl = @"http://www.cdc.gov/anthrax/";

}
```

and then I gave each alert it's own tag:

```
- (IBAction)bainfo:(id)sender {

UIAlertView *baAlert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:@"More Information", nil];

baAlert.tag=1;
[baAlert show];
}
```

Each tag called a different method:

```
 -(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

if (buttonIndex == 1){
    if (alertView.tag==1) {

        [self moreInfo];
    }
}
```

The methods performed the segues:

```
-(void) moreInfo{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"morebainfo" sender:nil];

}
```

Fianlly, in the viewdidLoad of the webviewcontroller, I added:

```
NSURL *WebUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:self.loadUrl];
NSURLRequest *WebRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:WebUrl];
[MoreInfoWeb loadRequest:WebRequest];
```

And that worked! the main thing that helped was moving the prepare for segue method to the initial view controller instead of the webview controller